# Writing to a file with functions

Tags: java

Develop a program that computes and records an individual's Body Mass Index (BMI) and stores it in a file. The BMI can be determined using two distinct formulas, one for the Metric system and another for the Imperial system:

Metric formula:
BMI = kilograms / meters<sup>2</sup>

Imperial formula:
BMI = (Pounds x 703) / inches<sup>2</sup>

The program must incorporate two separate functions, one for the Metric system and the other for the Imperial system. After calculating the BMI within these functions, return the value to the main function. In the main function, store this computed value in a file named "BMI.txt" along with the individual's name, following the format shown in the provided screenshots. Subsequent program executions should append new values to the bottom of the text file, preserving a record of prior BMI calculations, as illustrated in the last screenshot.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class BMI {
    static void metric() {
        Scanner inVal = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your weight, in kilograms: ");
        double kilograms = inVal.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your height, in meters: ");
        double meters = inVal.nextInt();

        double metricbmi = (kilograms) / (meters * meters);
    }
    static void imperial() {
        Scanner inVal = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your weight, in pounds: ");
        double pounds = inVal.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your height, in inches: ");
        double inches = inVal.nextInt();

        double imperialbmi = (pounds * 703) / (inches * inches);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        Scanner inVal = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate BMI in metric system or 2 for imperial system: ");
        int system = inVal.nextInt();

        if (system == 1) {
            metric();
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("BMI.txt");
            outputFile.println(name + " BMI is: " + metricbmi);

            outputFile.close();// Close the file.
            System.out.println("Result has been appended to the BMI.txt file!");

        }
        else if (system == 2) {
            imperial();
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("BMI.txt");
            outputFile.println(name + " BMI is: " + imperialbmi);

            outputFile.close();// Close the file.
            System.out.println("Result has been appended to the BMI.txt file!");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice!");
        }

    }
}
```

I have both of my functions set up, however I cannot figure out how to append the output of the functions to a file in the main function.

Comment: OT: But `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` and `Scanner inVal = new Scanner(System.in);`? Why do you create two scanners for standard input? You only need one.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) ?  It has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) that accepts a `boolean append` flag.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that the numbers computed in the `imperial()` and `metric()` functions cannot be used outside of the function code.
To see why, please consider the much simpler example

```
class example {
  static void f(){
    int v = 42;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(v);
  }
}
```

Running this code snippet will result in an error because the variable v is not known outside the **scope** of its declaration.
Scope are basically places in your code, defined by '{' and  '}'. Anything declared inside a scope is unknown outside of it.
Consider two classes in a single java file. The methods of the first class are not existing for the second class, even if both are written in the same file.
On the other hand, if you are in a scope *inside* another scope, then all the definitions form the outer scope are available inside the inner scope.

```
class f {
  int a = 18;
  
  public void g(){
    int b = 2*a
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Here, everything works fine because `g` access `a`, and both are in the same scope, so `a` is known inside `g`. However, if you followed well, you should see that `b` is not accessible in the `main` function.

With all this in mind, you can see that the code inside the `main` function cannot be executed because it tries to get the value of a variable, either `imperialbmi` or `metricbmi` which does not exist in it scope.

To solve your problem, you could either make your `imperial()` and `metric()` functions return the value or set up a variable existing in the scope of the class. I recommend the first option which makes more sense in your context.
As a side note, the naming convention in Java is camelCase for the variable names, it's a good habit to start using it. ( `metricbmi` becomes `metricBmi` for example )